# \newcommand for a specific chapter

Tags: macros, lyx, pstricks

I write a document with LyX, to which I add PSTricks pictures in ERT sections.

I defined a `\newcommand` in a certain ERT section, and it was available during this ERT section, but not available in the next ERT section.

I don't want to define this command in the preamble, because it is specific to a chapter.

How can I define a `\newcommand` that will be available in all ERT sections of a given chapter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the chapter title hit `Ctrl-L` for ERT and then insert

```
\begingroup
\newcommand...
```

and then leave the ERT mode. *Before* the next chapter (the end of the current one) insert also with ERT

```
\endgroup
```